# I'm not sure how classes work. Why wont my java file compile?

Tags: java, class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Item {
public static void main(String[] arrstring) {
    Item[] item2 = new Item[]{new Item("eggs", 2.99), new Item("milk", 3.99),
     new Item("broccoli", 2.75), new Item("bread", 3.25), new Item("apple", 1.25)};
    Cart cart = new Cart();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the virtual grocery store!");
    int x = 0;
    while (x != 4) {
        int y;
        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1: View available items");
        System.out.println("2: View your cart");
        System.out.println("3: Add an item to your cart");
        System.out.println("4: Check out");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        x = input.nextInt();
        if (x == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nAvailable Items:");
            for (y = 0; y < item2.length; y++) {
                System.out.print("" + y + ": ");
                items[y]Item.print();
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (x == 2) {
            Cart.printItems();
            System.out.println("Total cost: $" + Cart.getTotal());
            continue;
        }
        if (x == 3) {
            System.out.print("\nWhich item would you like to add? ");
            y = input.nextInt();
            Cart.addItem(item2[y]);
            continue;
        }
        if (x != 4) continue;
        System.out.println("\nThat will be $" + cart.getTotal() + ".");
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
    }
}
}
class Cart {
private Item[] items = new Item[100];
private int numItems = 0;

public void addItem(Item item) {
    items[numItems] = item;
    numItems++;
}
public void printItems() {
    if (numItems == 0) {
        System.out.println("\nYour cart is empty.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\nYour cart:");
        for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
            items[i]Item.print();
        }
    }
}

public double getTotal() {
    double d = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        d += items[i]Item.getPrice();
    }
    return d;
}
}
class Item {
private String name;
private double price;

public Item(String string, double j) {
    name = string;
    price = j;
}

public void print() {
    System.out.println(name + ": $" + price);
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
}
```

Errors:

```
Item.java:24: error: not a statement
                items[y]Item.print();
                     ^
Item.java:24: error: ';' expected
                items[y]Item.print();
                        ^
Item.java:59: error: not a statement
            items[i]Item.print();
                 ^
Item.java:59: error: ';' expected
            items[i]Item.print();
                    ^
4 errors
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with my classes and calling them back to the main method. Any help is much appreciated. I'm trying to make a virtual shopping cart with the items I included in the above array. I also want to be able to see each item in my cart and calculate the total. The bottom of the code has my error messages.

Comment: The compiler will tell you why something won't compile.  You should include those error messages in your question.

Comment: What do you think `items[y]Item` should represent/do? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1):

To use print() of the i<sup>th</sup> item in the array the command should be

`items[i].print();`

You don't have to tell Java that you are using Item.print() because items[i] is already an Item. If you do need to use a method from a different class you must cast the object like this

`(Item) arrayOfItemChildrenObjects[i].print();`

Answer (score 0):

There are two definitions of Item. One name must be changed:

this at the begining seems to refer as second Item constructor:

```
new Item("eggs", 2.99)
```

this is not valid: items[i]Item.getPrice();

Cart is undefined.

Comment: It still won't compile.
EDIT: Below the code are my error messages

Comment: you have two Item class still

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10616953)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer the question is "why wont my java file compile". The answer is that (and surely other problems ...)

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina You might consider re-phrasing the post ... right now it looks like a question rather than an answer.